# How to write CSS for each "ID" inside a main "Class"

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when writing the proper CSS code for a given HTML snippet.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="FourSquares">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
    <div id="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

I need to set the location of `id` named **first**. Here's the common CSS attributes for all `div` tags.

```
.FourSquares{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 130px;
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But I need to set the location of each `id` differently. I tried this method but it does not work.

```
.FourSquares .first{
    left: 260px;
    top: 785px;
}
```

Can you anyone please help me to understand **how to properly write the CSS** code for instances like this?

Comment: `.FourSquares #first`, first is an id, not a class.

Comment: Why don't you use classes instead?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey: Why use classes bu IDs???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect use of id in code css.

The id Attribute

```
<div class="FourSquares">
    <div id="first"></div>
</div>
```

then define a style for the element with the specific id:

```
.ForSquares #first {
    left: 260px;
    top: 785px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `.first`: Selects all elements with class="first"
>
> `#first`: Selects the element with id="first"

*you use of `id` in html code, so :*

**Change :**

```
.FourSquares .first{
```

**To:**

```
.FourSquares #first{
```